# How to return subtype from superclass method instead of superclass type

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript2.0, typescript-generics

I think this is an issue of implementing generics correctly, but I am not sure.

I created a Github gist representing the problem here:
https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/66b72b4b85262d957cb03ad097e4743e

Say I have this superclass:

```
  class A {

    foo(): A {
      return this;
    }

  }
```

and several subclasses, one for example looks like so:

```
   class B extends A {

     bar(): B {
      return this;
     }

   }
```

so if I do

`new B().foo().bar()`

this will work at runtime, but it **doesn't compile** with TypeScript. That's because `foo()` declares the return type to be `A`, not type `B`.

How can I return the type that `this` is, instead of declaring `foo()` to always return type `A`?

I tried this:

[image]

but I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to return the type of `this` using a [polymorphic this type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types).

```
abstract class A {
    foo(): this {
        return this;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    bar(): this {
        return this;
    }
}
```

which will allow for

```
const b = new B();

b.foo().bar();
```

Comment: is there a way to return a new instance of `this`?

Comment: @DAnsermino if you wish so. You can do `return new B as this` from within `B::bar`.

Comment: How can I do this for static methods ? `static foo(obj:<SubClass>):<SubClass>{ return obj; }` . `this` type cannot be used in static context.

Answer (score 1):

I have two examples for you, one with overloads and one with a generic interface.

## Overloads

If you meant for the `new C().foo().zoom()` version to work, you can achieve that, while still getting a warning about the `bar()` mistake with the following code, which creates a compatible overload that returns a subtype of the type in the parent class:

```
class A {
  foo(): A {
    return this;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  foo(): B {
    return this;
  }

  bar(): B {
    return this;
  }
}

class C extends A {
  foo(): C {
    return this;
  }

  zoom(): C {
    return this;
  }
}

const result = new C().foo().zoom();
```

If the real method in your code actually does something you want to re-use, you can call `super.foo()`... but in the example code that isn't needed.

```
  foo(): C {
    const a = super.foo();
    // You still need to return this, as it is a C, not an A.
    return this;
  }
```

## Generics

You can't make the base class generic, in order to return a type `T`. You can't use a class as a type constraint on its own type argument. You also have a problem with `A` not being guaranteed compatible with a `T` that extends `A`.

What you *could* do is introduce an interface, and use it on each class:

```
interface Fooable<T> {
  foo(): T;
}

class A {
  foo(): any {
    return this;
  }
}

class B extends A implements Fooable<C> {
  bar(): B {
    return this;
  }
}

class C extends A implements Fooable<C> {
  zoom(): C {
    return this;
  }
}

const result = new C().foo().zoom();
```

Comment: this isn't it, the problem is that `foo()` declares its return type to be A  `foo(): A`, but I need it to be whatever the type of `this` is, which is likely to `B` or `C`, not `A`.

Comment: I made a mistake in the question, I corrected it - I meant `new B()`, not `new C()`

Comment: I would have made `A` a generic class to solve this, but to do that properly you'd need to have `class A<T extends A>` and you can't use a class as a type constraint for its own generic type parameter.

Comment: I created a Github gist, and put the link in the question, you can copy the gist to a .ts file and you will see the problem.

Comment: sorry to ask this, but I improved the question, originally a mistake in the question caused you to answer a different question than was intended, please update the answer as you now see fit.

Comment: if you can get rid of C in your examples that would help, the C class doesn't really add any value to the question, so I removed it

Comment: We have an answer to the question, see @Shane's answer

Comment: Apologies for the imperfect question, but I provided an upvote anyway